# Test function in Kotlin cannot find function in main module

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a standard (multi-)project set-up in Kotlin using gradle, where I have a /src/main/kotlin/ and a /src/test/kotlin/.

I have a function in my main module that I would like to test, but when i create a test function in the same named directory in the test module, the function I wish to test isn't found and is not callable.

For reference, the root build.gradle

```
    ext.kotlin_version='1.3.61'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
        implementation "org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:1.0.0-beta5"
        implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9"
        implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-math4"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:1.2.6"

        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
        testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
        testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    }

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
    }

    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
            apiVersion = '1.3'
            languageVersion = '1.3'
        }
    }
}
```

and the sub-project build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-math4"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where in this project structure are the two sources placed?

Comment: Can't do a nice tree depiction, but the function to be tested is in transmog/lda/src/main/kotlin/moe.transmog.lda/utils/util.kt and the test class is in transmog/lda/sec/test/kotlin/moe.transmog.lda/utils/utilTest kt